# Citrix receiver 13 + Linux: serial port redirection

Tags: linux, serial-port, citrix

Simple question - how to **map serial port** (serial2USB as /dev/ttyUSB0) to XenApp with **Citrix receiver 13** on Linux (Ubuntu 13)?

With Citrix receiver 12, I can run connection manager (wfcmgr) and map desired port in preferences, but CR13 dont have this manager. I tried to manually edit wfclient.ini and put there these lines (copied from wfclient.ini used by CR12):

```
LastComPortNum=1
ComPort1=/dev/ttyUSB0
```

But nothing happened. In addition, I found this [link](http://faq.igel.com/otrs-igel/public.pl?Action=PublicFAQZoom;ItemID=619) so maybe I should ask: *How to redirect USB devices*? (and throw away this COM antique)

Answer (score 0):

So, lines in **wfclient.ini** are correct but I was operating with incorrect information that unix kernel v.2.4.20 (and higher) contains drivers for TFDI devices. Truth is that these drivers are in kernel v.2.6.31 (and higher). I should have to check **dmesg**... *sigh*